# SQLite query result not returned from function

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, promise

What I'm trying to do is create a kind of a storageservice in which I use a SQLite database to store key and value pairs after which I can retrieve them based on the key. To achieve this I set up the following code:

```
.service('StorageService', function($cordovaSQLite, $q) {

  if(window.cordova) {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("vouchers.db");
  } else {
    db = window.openDatabase("vouchers.db", "1.0", "Vouchers db", -1);
  }
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vouchers (key text, value text)");

  return {
    getItem: function(item) {
      var query = "SELECT key, value FROM vouchers WHERE key = ?";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[item]).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.rows[0].value);
        return result.rows[0].value;
        });
    },
    setItem: function(item, data) {
      var query = "INSERT INTO vouchers (key, value) VALUES (?,?)";
      return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [item, data]);
    }
  };
})
```

Now, most of this stuff is working great. I can store items in the db and even retrieve and log them from inside the function as you can see on the following line:

```
console.log(result.rows[0].value);
```

When I log this I get the expected value, but when I return it and log it in the controller where I'm using this service it's remaining undefined. The code in my controller looks as follows:

```
var test = StorageService.getItem("testje");
console.log(test);
```

Please note that there are NO console errors. Just two logs. One from the controller that is undefined, and one from the service that returns the value as intended:

```
controllers.js:465 undefined
services.js:122 dit is een testje!
```

I was hoping anyone can tell what is going wrong here. If there's any info or code that can be helpful and I left out, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `getItem: function(item) {` uses a promise to retrieve the results.

Try to change your code to this instead:

```
getItem: function(item) {
  var query = "SELECT key, value FROM vouchers WHERE key = ?";
  return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[item]);
});
```

and call your service this way:

```
StorageService.getItem("testje").then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

You'll be able to view the results then.

I suggest you to study some [basic principles](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) of promises: you'll encounter them very often if you use $http get and post requests and any other async stuff in javascript.